# Regex for \n not working

Tags: javascript

```
let text= "PLEASE UPDATE WITH NEW ZSP\n- Areas with significant";

let regex = "/\n/g";

text = text.replace(regex, "<br/>")
```

As you can see I'm trying to convert text with a regex and it still returns the same text including `\n`

Comment: `.replace()` expects a RegExp object, not a string - lose the quotes around your pattern for a start.

Comment: @Utkanos You should write that as an answer. That's the only thing that's wrong.

Comment: Done :) .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegExp literals in JavaScript are objects, not strings - lose the quotes around your pattern.

```
let regex = /\n/g;
```

Comment: Actually, it also allows a string. But then it just does a literal string replacement, not a regexp match.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant but my answer's a bit clumsy; editing... :)

Comment: thanks still not working this is a sample of string I need to escape `- Significant topo in S ~half of site\n- Stream near SW corner\n- NW corner looks OK\n- Isolated from neighbors by existing vegetation\n- Access along existing field road (~800', to be improved)`

Comment: @Mr.EasyAnswersMcFly [Looks fine to me.](https://jsfiddle.net/eyjrd51e/)